# How can I integrate google-API-spelling-java (API) in our selenium code to check the spellings?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

To check the grammar and spellings entire application

Comment: did you try out the "how to use it" on https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-spelling-java/ ?

Comment: Why with Selenium? Just send all the text from the code to the spelling API.